# GAction with restricted user access

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to deploy a google action with only limited user accces.
I would like to maintain users in the backend and allows access to only those user mail account.
Is there a way to acheieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alpha release for this.

As per document, Developer defined list of users can have access of your action.

Check [reference](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments#release-environment-comparison)

[image]

Another approach will be to use authentication in your action, take email of the user and have a webhook for your action. There you can check user email and respond to user according to your needs.